# Lambda Expression to find sum

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class as below:

```
public class Class2 {

private final Integer x;

private final Integer y;

public Class2(final Integer x, Integer y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Integer getX() {
    return x;
}

public Integer getY() {
    return y;
}

}
```

I have a Map object like below:

`Map<MyEnum , List<Class2>> mapX`

I want to find the sum of x & y members  of the Class2 instances in the List instance which is the value item in the above map. I want to use lambda expressions

I have come up with the following incomplete lambda. Thanks in advance.

```
        mapX.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println("MapX-Key : " + entry.getKey() + "\nMapX-Value : "
                    + entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(???)));
        });
```

Comment: It's still not clear what exactly do you want. Do you want to collect `sum(x+y)`? Also, what does `Class1` have to do with anything in your question?

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.summingInt(x -> x.getX() + x.getY())));` seems to work.

Comment: Usually you need `reduce` call for things like sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about what you're asking but one of these should help:

```
// Using Class2
Map<MyEnum , List<Class2>> mapX = null;
mapX.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println("MapX-Key : " + entry.getKey() + "\nMapX-Value : "
                + entry.getValue().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summingInt(x -> x.getX() + x.getY())));
});

// Values from Class2 via Class1
Map<MyEnum , List<Class1>> map1 = null;
map1.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println("MapX-Key : " + entry.getKey() + "\nMapX-Value : "
                + entry.getValue().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summingInt(x -> x.getClass2().getX() + x.getClass2().getY())));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go this way :

```
mapX.entrySet().stream()
               .map(entry -> "MapX-Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                           + "\nMapX-Value : " 
                           + entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getX() + e.getY()))
               .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will iterate over each `Entry`, then (`map`) create a String with the key, and then the sum of `x` and `y`, and at the end `print` them